# How can I play sound out of just one speaker in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, audio

I have a audio card that supports multiple speakers (Creative SB X-Fi).  What I am trying to do is write a program in C++ (Windows 7 Environment, Visual Studio IDE) that will play a given mono wav file to one of the 4 speakers I have hooked up.  Can anybody point me in the correct direction as to specific functions that will accomplish this aim?  My attempt to google a solution has not yielded fruit. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play sound through a set of surround sound speakers using DirectSound.  See the [MSDN page "Sounds in 3-D"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416965.aspx).

Comment: I had thought of doing something like that using OpenAL (another 3D audio library), but I couldn't figure out a way to make the sound come out of only one (or predominantly one) speaker.

Comment: Skimming the OpenAL guide, I see a section on "Multi-Channel Buffers" which looks like you would be able to control each speaker independently.  Have you already tried that?

Comment: This message from the openal mailing list looks like it might be helpful: http://opensource.creative.com/pipermail/openal/2009-April/011586.html

Comment: @Ben: I am a programmer by necessity rather than vocation, so I often find myself swimming out of my depth.  This is one such case. I hadn't seen that section and I am checking it out now.  If you know of particular functions that might complete this task in DirectSound I'd be fine with that too.  It is more important that I make the program work than I stick to any particular implementation.

Comment: I'll probably have to make another question; but I'm stuck at 'ALshort monodata[samples];'  In OpenAL the buffers seem to all be addressed by ID so I'm not sure how to get into the raw WAV samples in order to reassign them as discussed on the mailing list message.

Comment: @drknexus: Why don't you start with a simple synthesized sound, like a sine wave at 440 Hz (the A above middle C)?  That lets you separate out the "How do I control what speaker my sound comes out of?" question from other details like how to access the data in a .wav file.

Comment: @Ben: In OpenAL it looks like the programmer is protected from the contents of the buffer.  So I can't manually adjust the WAV contents the way the list suggests.  Which, incidentally, looks like it is just doing the same thing as what psmears suggests.  The only way to get that working in OpenAL is to modify the OpenAL source.  Sadly their subversion repository seems to be returning an error - so I can't try to do their modification in OpenAL.  I'm going to give psmears' suggestion a try this morning.

Comment: @drknexus: But you don't need to read an OpenAL buffer.  You need to read a .wav file and write to an OpenAL buffer (which `alBufferData` does).

Comment: @Ben: Yeah I know, but the OpenAL way of reading a .wav file seems to returns a pointer to the WAV data stream. I'm having difficulty figuring out how to get down the the representation that corresponds to ALshort monodata[samples]; in the list post you are referring to.

Comment: @drknexus: Does it work if you put in made-up data (e.g. a sine wave)?  If that works, you can attack accessing the .wav file.  It's a pretty simple file format (ok [it's not](http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/wavefiles.html), but finding the audio data inside is simple), or use any number of library functions that can be found by googling "read wav file".

Comment: I found some tutorials for accessing .wav files - oddly the work if I run the program from the command line but not from debug mode in Visual Studio and I haven't figured out why.  I have the target .wav in both the .sln directory and the debug directory (where the .exe is).  Because I don't know much about how sound files are formatted I was trying to avoid manually creating made-up data as it seemed my chances of screwing up were pretty large and there was no easy way to do a sanity check.

Comment: Using made-up data is easy: instead of `data71[i*8 + 6] = monodata[i];` inside the loop, do `data71[i*8 + 6] = 4000 * sin(440 * i * 2 * 3.14159 / 44100);` and `#include<math.h>`  For this quick test you don't need `monodata` at all.

Comment: @Ben:  I finally got there using the made-up data.  Thank you VERY much.  I can't really express how much I appreciate your assistance on this.  I also figured out what I was doing wrong with the .wav file placement - so now I look like I'm on track to wrap this project up.

Comment: @drknexus: Glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest trying Ben Voigt's answer first, since if that works out it will probably be easier and more flexible.

But if for some reason it doesn't, another alternative is as follows.

Basically, when you want to play the mono .wav out of a particular speaker, convert it to a 6-channel .wav that's silent on five of the channels, but contains the data from the mono .wav on the channel for the speaker you want it to play on.

This should be fairly easy to do, because the .wav file format is very simple. The basic idea is that the sound data in your mono .wav file will consist of (typically) two-byte pairs for each audio sample, for example:

```
1234 2ab3 def0 ce18 ....
```

To convert that data to multi-channel you need to insert silence (zero) for the other channels. For example, for channel 0 (front-left) you'd use:

```
1234 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 2ab3 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 def0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 (etc)
```

whereas for front-right you'd use:

```
0000 1234 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 2ab3 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 def0 0000 0000 0000 0000 (etc)
```

(Consult this [list of speaker assignments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surround_sound#Standard_speaker_channels) for the order.)

You also need to deal with the file's header, but the [wave file header format](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) is very simple; you'd need to change `NumChannels` from 1 to 6, `ByteRate` from whatever it is to the same value times 6, similarly for `BlockAlign` and `Subchunk2Size`.

NB I haven't actually tested any of the above, but it shouldn't take too much time to experiment. If it doesn't work, it may be necessary to add the newer WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE data to the file - more fiddly but still not too hard; here is a [useful page describing these extensions to the .wav format](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html).

Comment: Yeah, this is basically the same idea as in the mailing list I linked to, only yours writes it back to a file after expanding to multiple channels, and the one I found sends it to the sound card instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been trying BASS library?

http://www.un4seen.com/

> Multiple outputs
>   Simultaneously use multiple soundcards, and move channels between them